# Clipping line feature to MANY polygons for measurements

Tags: clip, length

I am looking to measure the length of stream segments(line) on numerous tax lot properties (Polygon).

Is there a tool that will allow me to "Cut" or "Clip" streams to tax lots to estimate not only length, but to create a buffer for each property and calculate area?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: That is two separate operations, the answer by GISI shows the first step (see this one about QGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18453/how-to-create-a-new-layer-from-overlap-between-two-layers) you haven't indicated software yet. I'm not sure about buffer and area, is there some sort of rule you're trying to apply? How would you determine the area from the buffer?

Answer (score 2):

The **Intersect** geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS can take line feature class (like streams) and intersect them with your polygon feature class (your tax properties). **The result would be a line feature class with the attributes of the streams and tax polygons**. The output line geometry will only exist where there's a polygon. The lines are split at the boundaries of the polygon as well. You could then look at processing the output for length's etc.

[The Intersect Tool: Link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000)