# QGIS 3.18 - Divide Polygons to smaller ones/clusters with each one having x number of points

Tags: qgis, polygon, openstreetmap, google-maps, aggregate-points

I have a polygon-layer with the boundaries of a district. I want to divide this polygon into several smaller polygons with each polygon having x number of buildings.

To do so, I added another (background layer with bing/google maps) and I started adding points in another layer (each point represent a building with automatic numbering). Then in another line layer, I draw manually the lines (around every x points/buildings) so that I can use later Split with line with the original polygon-layer

[image: manually]

The method is working but it is time consuming. Is there a way to speed up the process?
I found for example that OpenMaps can export the buildings shapes, but how can group each 30 buildings for example in a polygon?

Answer (score 2):

A basic workflow looks like this:

1. Download polygons for buildings using OpenStreetMap data with `QuickOSM plugin`.
2. Create centroid for the buildings.
3. On the centroid-layer, create an id-field for each of the points with the id of the original polygons they are located in. Use this expression: `array_first (overlay_within('poly', $id))` (replace `poly` with the name of your polygon layer).
4. Create Voronoi-polygons from the centroid-layer.
5. `Menu / Geoprocessing Tools / Union`: voronoi-polygons with the original polygon-layer.
6. Run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / k-means clustering`.

Comment: I think you mean this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354691/99589

Comment: I see, yes, basically, it's the same as far as I can see, just with `Union` instead of `Split with Lines` - if you post this comment under the question, I can delete my answer.

Comment: Let’s firstly wait for OP

Comment: I started following the workflow posted by Babel and I managed to create the centroid of the buildings downloaded: https://imgur.com/gUuVudt. I went to create the id-field using $id  then in another try using osm_id. However, when creating the voronoi-polygon it is looking like a mess https://imgur.com/W0GqxE1.  (using both $id and osm_id)
I am sure I made a mistake somewhere. 
@Taras  Does this method create clusters with a specific number of buildings/centroids (each cluster should have 30 close buildings)? Like already said, it looks similar

Comment: Everything is fine, that's how voronoi polygons look like. Get yourself comfortable with the concept of voronoi polygons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: Thanks.. 
The main polygon_layer is divided, however, it seems it is divided randomly. Some small polygon has 2 or 3 points/buildings inside them, others 10, others 1 etc...  I don't need the small polygons to be the same size of course but they should have the same number of points/buildings.

Comment: Please show your settings - after which step did you have this probelm?

Comment: Most probably the error is on step 3 (id_field): https://imgur.com/jRoLZdw .
 My layers settings: https://imgur.com/bK7KpbL .
 Buildings layer is the layer downloaded from OpenMaps and then converted to centroids
 Nabatiyeh is the layer that has the boundaries of the district (original polygon layer).
 Nabatiyé El-Tahta_Centroids is the layer that has the centroids from the Buildings layer.
 After Step 4 I get this : https://imgur.com/0gpFgHS .
 After Step 5: After union: https://imgur.com/a/KKHuqhb .

Comment: OK, after step 5 seelct only those of the resulting polygons that overlap with your orginal polygon. Use `Select by location`. You should than have 1 polygon per centroid - however very unevenly as regards size because your buildings are unevenly distributed.

Comment: Ok but even after that some polygons gave like 1 -2 points inside them and others 3 etc..  I need them all for example to have 5 points inside each

Comment: OK, than I mis-understood the question, I'm sorry for that: K-means clustering does not allow to set the cluster-size (a constant number of features to be grouped together). For this, see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/303657/88814

Comment: No worry. I have learned quite a few tricks and how voronoi  polygons work! Looking at the link, it seems that I need R for the script/functions. Too bad I have only worked with SPSS/Stata as statistical packages (I don't know R and I don't have access to ArcGIS for the other solutions)